# How to receive an invitation to visit South Korea

Tags: visas, paperwork, south-korea, invitation-letters, belarusian-citizens

I'm from Belarus, currently living in Vietnam. I would like to travel to South Korea, but need an invitation letter according to embassy pages, have turned to dozens of agencies, they cannot help. Could anyone send a link or share experience with getting an invitation letter.

Comment: http://visacentral.sg/requirements